# Add a new target into rules debian file

Tags: packaging, debian, makefile

I want to add a new target rule in `debian/rules` and I want it to be executed before `dpkg-source --before-build`.

This new target will generate a control file from a template file. How can I do that?

Comment: how about the patch target?

Comment: its not the same prob!

Comment: @JoBo Any doc for patch target?
thx

Comment: I resolved the prob by adding a DEBUILD_DPKG_BUILDPACKAGE_HOOK var in /etc/devscripts.conf.

I have just to specify path to my hook.


And everything is OK :).

Answer (score 4):

The OP solved the problem and [reported the solution in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337473/add-a-new-target-into-rules-debian-file#comment430851_337473):

> I resolved the prob by adding a DEBUILD_DPKG_BUILDPACKAGE_HOOK var in
>   /etc/devscripts.conf. I have just to specify path to my hook. And
>   everything is OK :)